# Matched case control study with household clusters

Tags: sas, cluster-analysis, analysis

I am trying to analyze a 3:1 matched case control study (matched on age and date of medical encounter) but realized that there may be household clusters represented among cases and controls. Cases were not matched to any controls who were household members, and controls in the same matched group were not siblings, either. My questions are:

1. Do we need to account for household clusters if cases and controls may be more similar to each other, despite not being matched to the same group?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes (which I think it is), how would one program this in SAS? Logically, I would use conditional logistic regression to analyze matched case control data and proc glimmix to account for household clustering, but I don't know how to account for both. Is there a way in SAS to account for household clustering using the glimmix procedure?

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Consider asking this on crossvalidated, aka https://stats.stackexchange.com/